# Localise or internationalise the date shown to moderators on deleted users

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools, timestamps

When a user is deleted and  a moderator visits their profile page (usually by manually navigating to the `/users/id` path), they see a few details:

> ```
> User was deleted on <date/time>
> User: <name> (<site id>) (Account.Id=<network id>) deleted by <moderator> (<mod id>)
> Reason: <deletion reason>
> ```

Great, that's handy. However, I've just managed to confuse myself looking at the date here, which is in American format. So, if I deleted a user on the 6th November in the early afternoon, the date reads `11/6/2015 1:06:35 PM`.

Can we either localise this so that it uses the date format specified by the user's locale, or internationali[sz]e it so that it reads `2015-11-06 13:06:35Z`?

Comment: I think there are some other places where this happens too.

Comment: Think it should be the same as the date is showing in all other places...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hovering over most dates here gives me `2015-11-06 13:06:35Z` format, which is why I suggested that.

Comment: Yeah, but still - think "User was deleted 2 hours ago" or "User was deleted on Jan 13 '14 at 19:45" is best.